# Крестики нолики Java - написать функцию для определения победителя или ничьей

Tags: java

Игра крестики - нолики на Java учимся определять победителя.

Для этого напишем универсальную функцию, которая принимает матрицу целых чисел N*N (1 <= N <= 300), значения могут быть:

0 — клетка свободна
1 — клетка занята первым игроком
2 — клетка занята вторым игроком
Функция должна возвращать:

1, если есть выигрышная комбинация для первого игрока
2, если есть выигрышная комбинация для второго игрока
-1, если уже никто победить не сможет (присутствуют 1 и 2 на любой строке, столбце, диагоналях)
0, если победителя еще нельзя определить
Выигрышная комбинация — вся строка или столбец, или диагональ заняты одним игроком.

Сигнатура функции
Название функции: determineWinner.

Параметры: int[][] grid.

Возвращаемый тип: int.

Примеры
Входные данные
grid = [ [ 1, 0, 2 ], [ 0, 1, 2 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ] ];
Выходные данные
result = 1;

Решила эту задачу. но не до конца. Очень прошу помочь разобраться, где именно я ошиблась
Мой Вопрос: Моя программа не верно выводит результат нечьей. Согласно моего кода работают все 8 кобминаций выигрыша. но результат 0 и -1 определяет не верно. Пожалуйста помогите разобраться.
Вот мой код:

```
public class TicTacToe_103 {
    public static int determineWinner(int[][] grid) {
        int result = -1;
        int n = grid.length;
        int maxId = n - 1; // последний элемент массива( строки)

        // проверяем комбинацию главная диагональ
        int[] arrayD = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arrayD[i] = grid[i][i];
        }
        result = winner(arrayD);

        if (result == 1 || result == 2) {
            return result;
        }
        //проверяем комбинации строк
        int [] arrayRow = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n && j < n; j++){
            arrayRow[j] = grid[i][j];
            if (j == maxId){
                j = -1;
                result = winner(arrayRow);
                if (result == 1 || result == 2) {
                    return result;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        // проверяем комбинации стобцов
        int [] arrayCol = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n && j < n; i++){
            arrayCol[i] = grid[i][j];
            if (i == maxId){
                i = -1;
                result = winner(arrayCol);
                if (result == 1 || result == 2){
                    return result;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        // проверяем комбинацию побочная диагональ
        int[] arrayDr = new int[n];
        for (int i = maxId; i >= 0; i--){
            arrayDr[i] = grid[i][maxId - i];
        }
        result = winner(arrayDr);
        if (result == 1 || result == 2){
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }
    // дополнительный метод на выигрыш
    public static int winner(int[] bestPlayer) {
        int result = 0;
        int n = bestPlayer.length;
        int count = 0;
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        // в цикле проходимся по ячейкам массива
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // если первая ячейка равна 1, то проверяем всю строку с помощью счетчика1
            if (bestPlayer[i] == 1) {
                count1++;
            }
            if (bestPlayer[i] == 0 && bestPlayer[1] == 1 && bestPlayer[i] == 2){
                count++;
            // иначе если ячейка массива равна 2, то проходим до конца всю строку счетчиком 2
            } else if(bestPlayer[i] == 2){
                count2++;
            }
        }
        if (count1 == n) {
            result = 1;
            return result;
        }if (count == n){
            result = 0;
            return result;
        }else if(count2 == n) {
            result = 2;
            return result;
        }else{
            result = -1;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] grid = {{1, 0, 2},{1, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 2}};
        determineWinner(grid);
        System.out.println(determineWinner(grid));
    }
}
```

Вот мой код с методом на проверку ничьей
Если кто-то может разобраться, то помогите пожалуйста, получается при вызове этого метода в функции, у меня блокируется дальнейшая проверка комбинаций выигрыша, например застревает код на главной диагонали и дальше не проверяет

```
public class TicTacToe_103 {
    public static int determineWinner(int[][] grid) {
        int isDraw = 0;
        int result = -1;
        int n = grid.length;
        int maxId = n - 1; // последний элемент массива( строки)

        // ----- проверяем на победителя комбинацию главная диагональ
        int[] arrayD = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arrayD[i] = grid[i][i];
        }
        result = winner(arrayD);

        if (result == 1 || result == 2) {
            return result;
        }
        // ------- проверяем на победителя комбинацию побочная диагональ
        int[] arrayDr = new int[n];
        for (int i = maxId; i >= 0; i--){
            arrayDr[i] = grid[i][maxId - i];
        }
        result = winner(arrayDr);
        if (result == 1 || result == 2){
            return result;
        }
        //-------------- проверяем на победителя комбинации строк
        int [] arrayRow = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n && j < n; j++){
            arrayRow[j] = grid[i][j];
            if (j == maxId){
                j = -1;
                result = winner(arrayRow);
                if (result == 1 || result == 2) {
                    return result;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        // ---------------проверяем на победителя комбинации стобцов
        int [] arrayCol = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n && j < n; i++) {
            arrayCol[i] = grid[i][j];
            if (i == maxId) {
                i = -1;
                result = winner(arrayCol);
                if (result == 1 || result == 2) {
                    return result;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        // проверка на ничью строк
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n && j < n; j++){
            arrayRow[j] = grid[i][j];
            if (result == draw(arrayD)) {
                result = -1;
                return result;
            }
            i++;
        }
        // проверка на ничью столбцов
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n && j < n; i++) {
            arrayCol[i] = grid[i][j];
            if (result == draw(arrayD)) {
                result = -1;
                return result;
            }
            j++;
        }
        /////  проверка на ничью второстепенной диагонали
        for (int i = maxId; i >= 0; i--){
            arrayDr[i] = grid[i][maxId - i];
        }
        if (result == draw(arrayD)) {
            result = -1;
            return result;
        }
        /// проверка на ничью главной диагонали
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arrayD[i] = grid[i][i];
        }
        if (result == draw(arrayD)) {
            result = -1;
            return result;
        }
        if (result != draw(arrayRow) && result != winner(arrayRow)
        && result != draw(arrayCol) && result != winner(arrayCol)
        && result != draw(arrayD) && result != winner(arrayD)
        && result != draw(arrayDr) && result != winner(arrayDr)){
            result = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
    // дополнительный метод на выигрыш
    public static int winner(int[] bestPlayer) {
        int result = 0;
        int n = bestPlayer.length;
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        // в цикле проходимся по ячейкам массива
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            // если первая ячейка равна 1, то проверяем всю строку с помощью счетчика1
            if (bestPlayer[i] == 1) {
                count1++;
            }
            // иначе если ячейка массива равна 2, то проходим до конца всю строку счетчиком 2
            else if(bestPlayer[i] == 2){
                count2++;
            }
        }
        if (count1 == n) {
            result = 1;
            return result;
        }if(count2 == n) {
            result = 2;
            return result;
        }else{
            result = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
    // метод для определения ничьей
    public static int draw(int [] nullWinner){
        int isDraw = 0;
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        int n = nullWinner.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if (nullWinner[i] != 2){
                count2++;
            }
        }if (count1 != 0 && count2 != 0){
            isDraw = -1;
        }else{
            isDraw = 0;
        }
        return isDraw;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] grid = {{1, 2, 2},{2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}};
        determineWinner(grid);
        System.out.println(determineWinner(grid));
    }
}
```

Здесь весь код, чтобы можно было разобраться знающему человеку где ошибка

Comment: В методе `winner()` нули считать не нужно. Выигрыш возможен не только когда все клетки свободны - он возможен пока, как минимум, две любые клетки не заняты обоими игроками. Приоритет условий: выиграл 1 -> выиграл 2 -> выигрыш невозможен -> результат неизвестен. Выигрыш невозможен когда количество занятых ячеек не равно нулю у обоих игроков. Результат неизвестен если ни одно из предыдущих условий не дало истину. Метод `determineWinner()` успешно определяет только победу, остальные ситуации равны проверке "побочной диагонали"

Comment: Я внесла изменения в свой код выше. Что касается метода  winner -  он работает. Прописала метод ничьей - draw Но когда я этот метод вызывая в функции - стопориться код на прохождении первой комбинации и дальше не проверяет - сразу пишет ответ, Что я не так сделала.  Наверное надо иначе метод вызвать.

Comment: Вам не нужен ещё один метод - всё уже проверено вызовами метода `winner()`, нужно только правильно обработать результаты всех его вызовов

Comment: с обработкой у меня как раз и проблема - пытаюсь решать, но никак - кручу- верчу запутать себя хочу - это про меня))) извините за плоский юмор. но совсем уже запуталась и голова пухнет....но решаю,

Comment: я новичок и эта задачка для меня достаточно не простая. хоть я уже большую часть решения вроде сделала. Сейчас просто понять где именно я что сделала не так. скорее всего в вызове метода, но как понять. что не так

Comment: Смотрите: ничья наступает тогда, когда во всех строках, столбцах и диагоналях есть оба игрока, то есть все вызовы `winner()` вернули `-1` - значит нужно после каждого вызова проверить результат на `-1` и записать в переменную, если не равен. В конце метода проверить эту переменную. И в методе `winner()` не хватает проверки на ничью `if (count1 > 0 && count2 > 0) return -1`

Comment: Вы знаете я пробовала так делать, но у меня проверяет только одну комбинацию самую верхнюю в коде и дальше код не идет, поэтому пришлось создать циклы для проверки на ничью, я это сделала и код вроде бы  работает в  idee  но на платформе куда нужно сдат задачу не могу отправить там ошибка... не понимаю, что именно не так

Comment: у меня есть отдельный метод на ничью  draw  и я его вызываю для каждой комбинации

Comment: Если можете помочь найти ошибку в имеющемся коде - очень долго я над ним трудилась. чтобы сейчас переписывать по сути то же самое)) может можно как-то оттолкнуться от того что уже есть?

Comment: Я понимаю, что код длинный и можно было бы короче, но переписывать нет времени - надо сдавать решение.. иначе.. все пропало((( если можете помочь  - помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Мы ни к чему не придём, если после каждого совета вы будете добавлять в два раза больше кода и спрашивать что с новым кодом не так, не исправив старый. Я давал советы по первому варианту и по моему мнению их достаточно, чтобы доделать логику. Во втором вашем варианте больше лишнего кода, но проблемы те же.

Answer (score 0):

Изменил метод winner следующим образом:

```
public static int winner(int[] bestPlayer) {
    
    if (bestPlayer.equals(1) && bestPlayer.equals(2))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (bestPlayer.equals(1) && !bestPlayer.equals(2))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (bestPlayer.equals(2) && !bestPlayer.equals(1))
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Но на всякий случай советую перепроверить вычисления.

Comment: не вижу разницы между вот этими строчками: 
    if (bestPlayer.equals(1) && bestPlayer.equals(2))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (bestPlayer.equals(1) && !bestPlayer.equals(2))
    {
        return 1;

Comment: может я не все понимаю, но четко написано одинаково))

Comment: Первая строка проверяет на наличие отметок от 1 и второго игрока (например, если в строке будет 1 2 2 - то по этому условию должно вернуть: -1). Вторая строка осуществляет проверку на то, что строка содержит отметки только от первого игрока. Но код выше не дает верного решения. Измененная версия: https://www.onlinegdb.com/8uZeV5DFXD. Тут int заменены на Integer и используется конвертация массива в список. На всякий случай проверьте правильность вычислений.

Comment: К вашему вопросу о различии условий: строки отличаются тем, что во втором условии стоит отрицание.

Comment: а извините пожалуйста, не увидела сразу

Comment: @N000b, Ваш код всегда будет возвращать 0:  bestPlayer  - массив, при сравнении со скаляром всегда дает false.

Answer (score 0):

похоже проблема начинается с этого места:

```
    // проверка на ничью строк
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n && j < n; j++){
        arrayRow[j] = grid[i][j];
        if (result == draw(arrayD)) {
            result = -1;
            return result;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

1. Вы в цикле собираете строку и тут же в каждой итерации проверяете draw(arrayD). очень похоже на копи/пэйст-ошибку. к тому же цикл проходит не по строкам, а по главной диагонали, т.к. i++ и j++ выполняются рядом.
2. Обратите внимание на то, что в отличии от условия победителя, где достаточно было найти одну комбинацию, для ничьей необходимо проверит *все* комбинации прежде чем возвращать результат. т.о. return тут тоже лишний.
3. не понятна логика сравнения result == draw(...) : если победитель не найден, то result=0, а draw возвращает -1 если ничья иначе 0, тогда почему такое сравнение?
4. обратите внимание на то, что в draw() переменная count1 всегда 0, возможно Вы забыли инкрементировать ее аналогично count2.

***спойлер***

```
// проверка на ничью
int drawResult = draw(arrayD) * draw(arrayDr);
// если drawResult==0, то партия не определена
for(int i = 0; drawResult != 0 && i < n; i++) {
  drawResult *= draw(row(grid, i));
  drawResult *= draw(col(grid, i));
}
if (drawResult != 0)
  return -1;
return 0;
```

методы row и col возвращают соответственно строку и столбец массива.